# Which is correct, "ready to give" or "ready to take"?

Tags: word-choice

A company which develops a particular application for business persons has on their website the following:

> Ready to *give* a test drive? Request a Demo Now.

In my opinion, the correct sentence should be

> Ready to *take* a test drive? Request a Demo Now.

I think the customer would *take* a test drive, not *give* one. Which one is the correct sentence? Or are both okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. Generally a student takes a test, while a teacher gives a test. But you may hear 'give a test' meaning 'take a test'.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=give%20a%20test%20drive%2C%20take%20a%20test%20drive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20test%20drive%3B%2Cc0) show that 'take a test drive' is the more common expression.

Answer (score 2):

I think they're confusing an idiomatic expression and condensing it into a shorter incorrect sentence. My best guess is that the sentence they were aiming for was more along these lines:

> Ready to *give it a shot* and test drive? Request a Demo now.

You're right in that the correct grammatical expression is:

> Ready to take a test drive? Request a Demo Now.